# Помогите разобраться с ошибкой при Build APK

Tags: android, android-studio

проект запускается в эмуляторе нормально, но `Build APK` делать отказывается.

(`Clean Project` и `Rebuild Project` делал)

что значит ошибка при `Build APK`:

```
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes
:core:jar
:android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:android:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:android:compileDebugSources
:android:prePackageMarkerForDebug
:android:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"trouble processing \"java/awt/font/NumericShaper.class\":","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"when not building a core library.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"in your application\u0027s project, when using an IDE (such as","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Eclipse). If you are sure you\u0027re not intentionally defining a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what\u0027s","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"going on.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"It is also often of questionable legality.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"the \"--core-library\" option to suppress this error message.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"If you go ahead and use \"--core-library\" but are in fact","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"building an application, then be forewarned that your application","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"system. You will be to blame for this problem.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.","sources":[{}]}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"1 error; aborting","sources":[{}]}

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

`UPDATE`

в проекте несколько gradle

build.gradle (main)

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "myGame"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.5'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.0'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

build.gradle (android)

```html
android {
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 25
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mygdx.sidy"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 25
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives() { 
    file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs();
    file("libs/x86/").mkdirs();

    configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
        def outputDir = null
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")        
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
        if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
        if(outputDir != null) {
            copy {
                from zipTree(jar)
                into outputDir
                include "*.so"
            }
        }
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.mygdx.sidy/com.mygdx.sidy.AndroidLauncher'
}

// sets up the Android Eclipse project, using the old Ant based build.
eclipse {
    // need to specify Java source sets explicitly, SpringSource Gradle Eclipse plugin
    // ignores any nodes added in classpath.file.withXml
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs "src", 'gen'
        }
    }

    jdt {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.6
        targetCompatibility = 1.6
    }

    classpath {
        plusConfigurations += [ project.configurations.compile ]        
        containers 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK', 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES'       
    }

    project {
        name = appName + "-android"
        natures 'com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature'
        buildCommands.clear();
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ResourceManagerBuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.PreCompilerBuilder"
        buildCommand "org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder"
        buildCommand "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ApkBuilder"
    }
}

// sets up the Android Idea project, using the old Ant based build.
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("src");
        scopes = [ COMPILE: [plus:[project.configurations.compile]]]        

        iml {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                def builder = NodeBuilder.newInstance();
                builder.current = node;
                builder.component(name: "FacetManager") {
                    facet(type: "android", name: "Android") {
                        configuration {
                            option(name: "UPDATE_PROPERTY_FILES", value:"true")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

build.gradle (desktop)

```html
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.mygdx.sidy.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);
 
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse {
    project {
        name = appName + "-desktop"
        linkedResource name: 'assets', type: '2', location: 'PARENT-1-PROJECT_LOC/android/assets'
    }
}

task afterEclipseImport(description: "Post processing after project generation", group: "IDE") {
  doLast {
    def classpath = new XmlParser().parse(file(".classpath"))
    new Node(classpath, "classpathentry", [ kind: 'src', path: 'assets' ]);
    def writer = new FileWriter(file(".classpath"))
    def printer = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer))
    printer.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
    printer.print(classpath)
  }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в конфиг прогварда `-keepattributes Exceptions, Signature, InnerClasses`.

Comment: @post_zeew, а причем здесь `ProGuard`? До недавнего времени APK собирался. Сторонние библиотеки не подключались.

Comment: @ravend а вы ничего в системных классах не меняли? Нигде зарезервированными словами переменные не называли? Пространства имен везде корректные? Ибо по тексту именно это причина вашей ошибки.

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky, вроде ничего экзотичного не делал, тихо починял свой примус. Если все так плохо почему тогда в эмуляторе запускается?

Comment: @ravend прикрепите свой gradle - есть подозрение что вы все же используете сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: @ravend Точнее вы используете AWT из Java а не из либы для Android.

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky, выложил в вопросе

Comment: @ravend посмотрите эти ссылки: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387897/cant-generate-apk-because-of-trouble-processing-java-awt-font-numericshaper-cl и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266853/attempted-to-fix-androids-ill-advised-or-mistaken-usage-of-a-core-class-went-b увы у вас Maven, не особо в курсе как он работает.